# Remove square brackets from the JSON output

Tags: java, json

Hello all i wanted to remove the square brackets from the json output.

```
[
  {
    "author": "Mark Twain",
    "book": "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer",
    "cost": "$68",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "author": "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    "book": "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes",
    "cost": "$97",
    "id": "2"
  }
]
```

I have used the below one to remove the brackets and get the output if i am correct

```
List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
list=(List<Book>)JSONArray.toList(
    JSONArray.fromObject(books.values()),
    new Object(),
    new JsonConfig()
);
return list;
```

added the required jars.But my i am getting an error(console output)

```
WARNING: Tried to assign property author:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property book:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property cost:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property id:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property author:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property book:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property cost:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
Jul 29, 2016 5:16:45 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean

WARNING: Tried to assign property id:java.lang.String to bean of class java.lang.Object
```

and my postman gives me a 500 internal server error

Any help appreciated
Thank you

Comment: if you remove the brackets from the output it is no longer JSON, see http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: You need to convert json array into  Java Array list.

Comment: yea thats true.The exact issue is i am using iid v8.5.5. I am using this rest call in my bpm and trying to parse this json to xml using a XMLDataHandler provided by ibm.It starts parsing and find "[" and throws error"expected is { instead found [.

Comment: You are trying to assign a String into Object, that is the issue here.

Comment: You can read the JSON file from the second to the first to the last line like normal file instead and make a new file copy. @Dallen has a point.

Comment: thank you all issue is solved..